# How to calculate Edge states of Topological insulators

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, topological-insulators, topological-order, quantum-hall-effect

Topological insulators are novel state of matter in which bulk is insulator and edges are gapless. How do we calculate these gapless states? I am reading the following PRL

> Feng Liu and Katsunori Wakabayashi, *Novel Topological Phase with a Zero Berry Curvature* The pdf file is available [here](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.118.076803).

In this PRL they have plotted gapless states in figure.3 but they are not mentioning about how they plotted these states. Is there any simple model from which I can understand how to plot ribbon spectra of edges states (as they have done in this paper).
They are providing a Hamiltonian in last paragraph on page#1 from which I successfully plotted the energy band structure given in Figure.1 using MATLAB.

Comment: One way of plotting the edge spectra is to consider  Eq. 1 and perform a Fourier transformation along one direction, say(x), assuming periodic boundary condition, and treat another direction with open boundary. Then calculate the spectrum of this Hamiltonian with $k_{x}$. A nice example would be 2D quantum Hall effect in lattice http://rhodia.ph.tsukuba.ac.jp/~hatsugai/modules/pico/PDF./Riemann.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite straigthforward. First you write your hamiltonian in second quantization formalism in crsytal momentum basis.
Then you make a fourier transform to fermionic field operators such that, now they are in lattice site basis.
Now your hamiltonian is in form of 
$$\mathcal{H}=\sum_{i,j,\mathbf{k_{\perp}}}\Psi^{\dagger}_{j,\mathbf{k_{\perp}}}H_{i,j,\mathbf{k_{\perp}}}\Psi_{i,\mathbf{k_{\perp}}}$$
And if you find the eigen values of $H_{i,j,\mathbf{k_{\perp}}}$ with $ij$ determined by the size of your finite system the eigen values will look like the figure in your example.